# mirror on-prem nexus repository to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, nexus, mirror

We have a local on-prem nexus OSS repository for all of our maven builds.

In order to take advantage of some of the AWS offerings we would like to replicate the on-prem nexus repository over to s3.

The idea is that for example a build uploads a snapshot jar to nexus and then nexus subsequently mirrors the jar to s3 so that the snapshot jar also becomes available for services in AWS.

Is it possible to configure nexus OSS to replicate to s3 while also keeping the local nexus repositories and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

- One way to do that would be having an ec2-s3 connection. The ec2 could host your Nexus OSS v3, which provides the capability to use s3 as the blob store. But using this you won't be able to view jar directly in s3, they will only be available in nexus to be viewed.
- Assuming you achieved this above task, once your jar is present in Nexus, you can then download and push the jar to s3, where it can be directly visible.